# Modeling XNOR in Pyomo

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, constraint-programming

I am writing a nurse patient matching algorithm, and I want to incorporate something into the objective function that measures how well the new patient-nurse assignments match the patient-nurse assignments from the previous day. I've introduced a new binary variable model.MATCHES_PREVIOUS which should be equal to the XNOR operation of model.Prev_Assignments and model.Assignments (if both are 0 or both are 1, then model.MATCHES_PREVIOUS is 1, otherwise it is 0).

#Sets

```
model.PatientIDs  = {0, 1, 2}
model.NurseIDs = {a, b}
```

## Indexed parameter (indexed by (patient, nurse))

```
model.Prev_Assignments = {(0, a): 1, (0, b): 0, (1, a) : 0, (1, b) : 1, (2, a) : 1, (2, b) : 0}
```

## Indexed variable (indexed by (patient, nurse))

```
model.Assignments = {(0, a): 1, (0, b): 0, (1, a) : 0, (1, b) : 1, (2, a) : 0, (2, b) : 1}

model.Matches_Previous = {(0, a): 1, (0, b): 1, (1, a) : 1, (1, b) : 1, (2, a) : 0, (2, b) : 0}
```

Currently, I'm trying to implement this with the below constraint, which I thought was the proper way to translate XNOR into a linear expression:

```
def matches_previous(self, patient, nurse):
  return model.Matches_Previous[patient, nurse] == (model.Assignments[patient, nurse] * model.Prev_Assignments[patient, nurse]) + (1 - model.Assignments[patient, nurse])  * (1 - model.Prev_Assignments[patient, nurse])
```

In the objective function, I include (-model.Matches_Previous) along with the other components (since I am minimizing the objective, this would maximize model.Matches_Previous).

However, this isn't giving the behavior I want. Note that there are other aspects of the model which would motivate it to produce assignments that are different from the previous assignments (e.g. changing patient workloads), but I want it to match the previous assignments as best as possible.

Any idea how to implement this better? I looked into Pyomo.GDP and LogicalConstriants, but I haven't been able to get this to work and the documentation is lacking for these modeling extensions.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/ is better place for this type questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a strategy you might try.  Note your attempt above makes the problem non-linear by multiplying variables, which is probably NOT desired.

You can code the XNOR variable in linear fashion, assuming there is some "pressure" on it...  Let me explain.

In pseudocode:

```
Let X = binary variable
Let X_prev = other binary variable

Let P = binary variable {1: if X, X_prev are not equal, else 0}
```

So, we intend to make `P` a penalty that can be indexed (optionally) and summed up, then introduce 2 constraints

```
P >= X - X_prev
P >= X_prev - X
```

And in your objective function, use P to induce a *penalty* not a reward and it should work...  something like:

```
Obj = <some other components> + p_weight * sum(P)   ; minimized
```

Comment: This worked! I only had to change the constraints to include an = sign as well because my solver was giving me an error message, but the logic still works. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, that was just sloppy on my shorthand...  I'll edit.  glad it worked

Answer (score 4):

We always can write

```
 z = x xnor y
```

as

```
 z >= 1-x-y
 z <= 1-x+y
 z <= 1+x-y
 z >= x+y-1
```

where x,y,x are binary variables. This is rigorous (derivation is [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/06/xnor-as-linear-inequalities.html)) and tight (we can even relax z to be continuous between 0 and 1).

Sometimes we can drop the <= or >= inequalities because of how the objective (or constraint) works.